# How to resize a Splash Screen Image using Tkinter?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am working on a game for a school project and as a part of it a Splash Screen is to load to simulate the 'loading' of the game. I have the code and it does bring up the image, but what I want it to do is bring up the defined .gif file onto the screen. Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width*1, height*1, width*0, height*0))
image_file = "example.gif"
image = tk.PhotoImage(file=image_file)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=height*1, width=width*1, bg="darkgrey")
canvas.create_image(width*1/2, height*1/2, image=image)
canvas.pack()
root.after(5000, root.destroy)
root.mainloop()
```

My only issue is that because the image is larger than the screen it does not fit as a whole image. How can I resize the image using this code so that any .gif image fits on the screen?

P.S. Please do not make any real drastic changes to the code as this does what I want, value changes are ok.

Comment: Is the problem solved? If yes, please accept my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).
Here is the code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width*1, height*1, width*0, height*0))
image = Image.open(image_path)
image = image.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=height*1, width=width*1, bg="darkgrey")
canvas.create_image(width*1/2, height*1/2, image=image)
canvas.pack()
root.after(5000, root.destroy)
root.mainloop()
```

You get the width and height from:

```
width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
height = root.winfo_screenheight()
```

then call **resize()**

If you still want to use PhotoImage, you can try **zoom(x, y)** and **subsample(x, y)**. Here is the [doc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.PhotoImage-class.html). By the way, It's not work on my computer...(python2.7 + win7)